# Laravel download not work

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, download, response

I have a problem with **Laravel 5.2** and `Response::download()`

My code is very simple:

`file_get_contents("pathtofile/test.pdf");`

works perfectly, but this:

```
return Response::download('pathtofile/test.pdf', 'test.pdf', [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; ' . 'test',
]);
```

leaves me with:

> FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37: The file "pathtofile/test.pdf" does not exist

I have a shared drive between a linux server and windows and the files 
are on the windows server and my site is on the linux server.

Comment: I think your error is clear enough.. your provided path for the file is wrong. Check your current directory using getcwd(http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) before response, and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: My path is correct because `file_get_contents`  work

Comment: Try appending the `storage_path()` or `public_path()` to your `pathtofile/test.pdf` string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find response

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Type: $contentType");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        readfile($path);
```

works